# Can PXE be run over a multi-port bridged nic?

Tags: networking, pxe, bridging

I have a system which i've configured and tested with one ethernet port that acts as a PXE server, and it works.  I also have a quad port nic sitting around I'd like to utilize so I've been wondering if I bridge all of the ports on that nic together, would PXE blast out over all of those ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized I'm essentially trying to use my ports as a switch.  This covers it:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-network-interfaces-bridge-eth0-eth1-eth2/

Edit:  I got it working

```
#! /bin/bash
mount -o loop,ro archlinux-2015.05.01-dual.iso /mnt/archiso
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 enp0s8
brctl addif br0 enp0s9
brctl addif br0 enp0s10
brctl addif br0 enp0s17
brctl setfd br0 4
ip link set enp0s8 up
ip link set enp0s9 up
ip link set enp0s10 up
ip link set enp0s17 up
ip link set br0 up
ip addr add 192.168.0.1/24 dev br0
systemctl start dnsmasq
sudo -v
sudo darkhttpd /mnt/archiso &
```

I had thought the forwarding delay should have been set to 0, but some sources disagreed with that number.  I followed Cisco's suggestion and used 4.
The key seemed to be giving the bridge an IP address, once I did that it worked.